# Java while and if and else

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

```
public class Head1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int beerNum = 99;
    String word = "bottles";
    while (beerNum > 0) {
      if (beerNum == 1) {
        word = "bottle";
      }
      System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
      System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer");
      System.out.println("Take one down.");
      System.out.println("Pass it around.");
      beerNum = beerNum - 1;
      if (beerNum > 0) {
        System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
      }
      if (beerNum == 1) {
        System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
      } else {
        System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall!");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This example code from a Java book prints out the song from 99 bottles to no bottles of beer on the wall. The problem is that when it is 1 bottle of beer on the wall, it still says bottles. I tried to fix this by adding `if (beerNum == 1)` section at the end. But still, it shows 1 bottles of beer on the wall, i bottle of beer on the wall.

I don't know what to change to fix this. Do I create another while section?

If you can give em a hint so I can solve it on my own that would be cool too! Because I do understand that I the actual song output is in the first if section, but I don't know where I should edit "if" or if i should just create another if section.

Thanks!

Comment: This question shows lack of basic java knowledge...

Comment: Thats why I'm learning -_-

Comment: @Menelaos I dunno there's specific problem, relavant source code and good explanation what he has tried and what he is trying to do. It's well above the average question here :-)

Comment: @Esailija True, when you say it like that. Probably only title is too generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You update beerNum and then print it out. Put the section

```
if (beerNum == 1) {
    word = "bottle";
}
```

after the line where you update the value of beerNum. Using separate variables for "bottle" and "bottles" would also be a good idea.

Comment: Took me a bit longer then it should but I get it now! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the same without loops and use recursion.

```
public class Bottles {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        removeBottle(100);
    }

    private static void removeBottle(int numOfBottles) {
        // IF the number of bottles is LESS THAN OR EQUAL to 1 print singular version
        // ELSE print plural version
        if (numOfBottles <= 1) {
            System.out.println(numOfBottles + " bottle of beer on the wall.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(numOfBottles + " bottles of beer on the wall.");
        }

        // print of the rest of song
        System.out.println("Take one down.");
        System.out.println("Pass it around.\n"); // "\n" just puts new line

        numOfBottles--; // remove a bottle

        // IF the number of bottles is GREATER THAN OR EQUAL to 1 do it again!
        // ELSE no more bottles =(
        if (numOfBottles >= 1) {
            removeBottle(numOfBottles);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good way to get a stack overflow though. I personally find loops more readable too, in this particular case.

Comment: Ahhh that's a dif approach altogether, I already solved it, but thanks anyways!

Comment: @LearnIT, its good to keep it in mind, will come handy later on.

Comment: @RaptorDotCpp, it will only cause a stack overflow if you don't terminate it properly. its basically like a while-loop. I do agree loops are easier to read, but I think recursion in some situation are faster.

Comment: Or  if your stack grows too big. Ofcourse that wouldn't happen here. Not on any modern machine.

Comment: What I ended up doing is putting in if (beernum==1) and printed out the song using a new variable called sWord="bottle";, and just ended it with no more bottles of beet on the wall! no else statement needed!